# Traverse and Accessing inner elements in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm having a nested JSON document and want to update elements in it. Below is the JSON file.
Have validated this JSON via online formatting multiple times as well.

```
{
    "j1": [{
        "URL": "http://localhost/",
        "Data": "{\"dump\":[{values:[{time:1586826385724,val:5.12},{time:1587576460460,val:3.312}]}]}"
    }]
}
```

In this, I want to access 'values'  and add element name: ABC and name: CBA in the subsequent entries.

```
{values:[{name:'ABC',time:1586826385724,val:5.12},
{name:'CBA',time:1587576460460,val:3.312}]}
```

Now with below code am getting a dictionary data but am not sure how to access the samples and its values through this dict.

## Trying with dict object

```
import json
   with open("new1.json") as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)
   data['json1'][0]['DownloadData'][0:]
```

I tried using **objectpath** library for json element traversing but fetching empty result-set

```
#trying with objectpath lib
 import json
    import objectpath
    with open("new1.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    jsonnn_tree = objectpath.Tree(data['json1'])    
    result_tuple = tuple(jsonnn_tree.execute('$..values'))
```

I do understand shouldn't ask for direct code, but not able to find anything relevant in this context on accessing nested JSON / dictionary. Being a novice, thought of seeking some guidance here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it looks that you have a nested JSON string here. And inner JSON isn't valid. So we have to fix it before parsing.

```
import json
with open("new1.json") as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)
innerstr = data["j1"][0]["Data"]
innerstr = innerstr.replace("values",'"walues"').replace("time",'"time"').replace("val",'"val"').replace("walues","values")
inner = json.loads(innerstr)
#then we can modify inner data as we want
inner["dump"][0]["values"][0]["name"] = "ABC"
inner["dump"][0]["values"][1]["name"] = "CBA"
```

And now we has `inner`variable like this

```
{'dump': [{'values': [{'name': 'ABC', 'time': 1586826385724, 'val': 5.12},
                      {'name': 'CBA', 'time': 1587576460460, 'val': 3.312}]}]}
```

Comment: this is a sample. Can you suggest the edit here for values?

Comment: When I wrote your JSON to python variable I needed to first escape backlash and then use it for escaping quote. That's why there is double backlashes .

Comment: updating one sample JSON would be feasible, but there would be many files to process, adding both backlash and " " would be difficult. Any approach to add these via code?   str1=data['j1'][0]['Data'][19:108]  was using this as a workaround to fetch the values string.

Comment: Ok, so that reflects the real data you have. I update my answer in way you can read your data from file as it is.

Answer (score 4):

It is a **Relaxed JSON** format. There is a [A relaxed JSON parser for Python](https://github.com/simon-engledew/relaxedjson.py).
Here is the example:

```
>>> import relaxedjson
>>> relaxedjson.parse('{moose: "goose"}')
{'moose': 'goose'}
```